# How to reduce the verbose redundancy of java thread local

Tags: java, thread-local

I have a class and I want declare a private member which is a thread local dictionary.  So this is how it looks...

```
private static ThreadLocal<HashMap<Integer, Measurement>> measurements = 
        new ThreadLocal<HashMap<Integer, Measurement>>() 
{
    @Override protected HashMap<Integer, Measurement> initialValue()
    {
        return new HashMap<Integer, Measurement>();
    }

};
```

As you can see I have to type `HashMap<Integer, Measurement>` an absurd number of times. Is there any way to make this more succinct?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about this ?

```java
private static ThreadLocal<HashMap<Integer, Measurement>> measurements = ThreadLocal.withInitial(HashMap::new);
```